# How to generate all combinations of integers of any size dynamically

Tags: java, for-loop, dynamic, size, combinations

I have this function:

```
public void func1(int d, double delta, double min, double max ) 
{
    if( d == 1 )
    {
        for( double i=min ; i <= max ; i++ )
            System.out.println(i);

    }

    if(d == 2 )
    {
        for( double i=min ; i <= max ; i++ )
            for( int j = min ; j <= max ; j++ )
                System.out.println(i, j);

    }

    if(d == 3 )
    {
        for( double i=min ; i <= max ; i++ )
            for( int j = min ; j <= max ; j++ )
                for( int k=min ; k <= max ; k++ )
                    System.out.println(i, j, k );

    }
}
```

How to make it dynamic? I.e.,: how to **not** use the `if` statement so that the function can work with any given `d`?
Currently, if I want the function to work with d=5, then I have to write five nested for loops and add an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the idea of [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to tackle this problem. The key idea is that if you want to have `d` loops, you can simply have a single for-loop, and within that for-loop you will have a function that loops `d - 1` times:

```
loop(int d) {
    for (i = min : max) {
        loop(d - 1)
    }
}
```

You may refer to the following sample code for reference:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        func1(3, 1.0, 3.0);
    }

    private static void func1(int d, double min, double max) {
        func1(d, min, max, "");
    }

    private static void func1(int d, double min, double max, String prefix) {
        if (d == 0) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
        } else {
            for (double i = min; i <= max; i++) {
                if (d == 1) {
                    func1(d - 1, min, max, prefix + i);
                } else {
                    func1(d - 1, min, max, prefix + i + ", ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update

I have modified the code in order to return an array of the double values instead of a string:

```
public class Main {

    private static List<double[]> combination = new LinkedList<>();
    private static double[] tmpArray;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        func1(3, 1.0, 3.0);

        for (double[] result : combination) {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                if (i != result.length - 1) {
                    System.out.print(result[i] + ", ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(result[i]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void func1(int d, double min, double max) {
        tmpArray = new double[d];
        func2(d, min, max);
    }

    private static void func2(int d, double min, double max) {
        if (d == 0) {
            //System.out.println(prefix);
            double[] newArray = new double[tmpArray.length];
            System.arraycopy(tmpArray, 0, newArray, 0, tmpArray.length);
            combination.add(newArray);
        } else {
            for (double i = min; i <= max; i++) {
                tmpArray[d - 1] = i;
                func2(d - 1, min, max);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good. BUT i don't have access to the individual numbers, for example, if I want to create a double array of size d=3 where the elements are i,j,k .

Comment: I can parse the string return by the function and convert into double values, but is there a direct way?

Comment: I think the better way would be to store the values in an array, or a `List`. You may even define your own class to handle that too. I would prefer doing it this way instead of parsing the string

Comment: @user1728624 I have updated my code to address this accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a homework question but I'll bite.

My answer works like an odometer on a car. You have wheels of digits. When each wheel gets to 9, the next one gets bumped up a slot and the current one return to 0. It uses no recursion and maintain the full array of numbers at all time. Instead of `println`, you can add the array to a list of array to capture all permutations. (The last time I touched Java was in 2004 so pardon me if this doesn't look "modern")

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void func1(int d, double delta, double min, double max ) {
        double[] arr = new double[d];
        int i,j;

        for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
            arr[i] = min;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        while (true) {
            // increase the first slot
            while (arr[0] < max) {
                arr[0] += delta;
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            }

            // find the next slot to increase
            i = 1;
            while (i < d && arr[i] == max) {
                i++;
            }

            // test of all slots contain the max value
            Boolean allMax = true;
            for (j = 0; j < d; j++) {
                if (arr[j] != max) {
                    allMax = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (allMax) {
                // if it does, quit the outer while loop
                break;
            } else if (i < d) {
                // if not, increase that next slot
                arr[i] += delta;
            }

            // reset all slots before it
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                arr[j] = min;
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }


     public static void main(String []args) {
        func1(3, 1, 1, 3); // gives 3^3 = 27 permutations
     }
}
```

There are a couple assumptions that I've made:

- `min < max`
- `delta` steps perfectly from `min` to `max`. For example, `delta = 1, min = 1, max = 10`. I haven't tested cases like `delta = 2, min = 1, max = 2`.